# Help me get on to Area 51

Tags: bug

I got an [Area 51 account](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/163052/kingledion?tab=stats) on Oct 22 last year, but since Feb 25 this year, I haven't been able to log in.

When I attempt to log in I see an error like:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> An unexpected error occurred while logging in. It's not you, it's us.
>   This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has
>   automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

There is something wrong with my OpenID. However, if you take a look at my [OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) page, even though I have 12 failed attempts to validate Area 51, I was able to authenticate Data.SE just yesterday.

I followed the [account recovery steps](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) but that just leads me back to the original error message when I try to log on.

I can't find an Area 51 meta or anything to post onto, possibly because I don't have an Area 51 login, so I thought I'd ask here and see if anyone can point me to the right direction. How do I get a hold of someone who can fix my OpenID so that I can participate in Area 51?

Comment: This might be better for [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Area 51 login has quite a few problems, by the way: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=area+51+login. One of those may match yours. On a related note, there is [an Area 51 discussion zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/); I don't know if that will let you log on.

Comment: @HDE226868 Scratch that, I actually can log in to discussion, as long as I go straight there, and don't try to go to the Area51 main site. If I enter the address area51.meta.stackexchange.com into a browser, I authenticate, but if I do area51.stackexchange.com I don't. So wierd!

Comment: That's absolutely bizarre. I wonder what the problem could be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the HTTPS Everywhere browser add-on, [that might be your problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303934/162102).  Otherwise, someone else recently made [a similar support request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304008/162102) that got fixed, so I'd try there.

Area 51 has the "discussion" site, which is sort of like their per-site meta, but of course it's hard to post if you can't log in.  Meta.SE is also an appropriate place to take questions about Area 51 itself.

Comment: I pinged the dev in your second link and got the problem fixed. Thanks!